# Unlist a data.frame column

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that contains the data of a facebook page with 167 objects

I then take the "message" column and separate the hashtags from it with stringr. This produces a list called "hashes" of 67.

```
msg <- page$message
hashes <- str_extract_all(msg,"#\\S+")
```

I then append hashes to an empty column I created, called hashtags.

```
page$hashtags <- NA
page$hashtags <- hashes
```

However the column "hashtags" is now a list. If I `unlist(page$hashtags)` everything turns into `NA`.

Conversely, if I unlist "hashes", I can't find a way to re-append this to the data.frame because they have different numbers of objects.

I feel like I'm missing something simple and need something from the `apply` family or `dplyr`?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For unlisting list-columns, you need to call `unnest` from the `tidyr` package.

`unnest(dataframe, nameofcolumns)`

Best,

Colin

Comment: Always glad to help! If it works, you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).Thanks, Colin.

Comment: Hey Colin, question for you. Using unnest returns a data.frame of 61 rows. How can I unnest and preserve the entire 167 rows of the original data.frame?

Comment: So concise and clean-- this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for sharing!!!